# Splitting String based on letters case

Tags: r

I want to split the following string

```
"ATextIWantToDisplayWithSpaces"
```

like this

```
A Text I Want To Display With Spaces.
```

I tried this code in `R`

```
strsplit(x="ATextIWantToDisplayWithSpaces", split=[:upper:])
```

which produces this error

```
Error: unexpected '[' in "strsplit(x="ATextIWantToDisplayWithSpaces", split=["
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just do this. It works by (a) locating an upper case letter, (b) capturing it in a group and (c) replacing it with the same with a space preceding it.

```
gsub('([[:upper:]])', ' \\1', x)
```

Comment: excellent! Here is a slight modification by removing the first white space: `gsub("(?!^)(?=[[:upper:]])", " ", x, perl=T)`

Comment: `gsub('([[:upper:]])', ' \\1', x)` put extra space in the beginning if the first letter is in upper case but `gsub("(?!^)(?=[[:upper:]])", " ", x, perl=T)` don't.

Comment: or this which also does not insert a space at the beginning: `gsub("(.)([[:upper:]])", "\\1 \\2", x)`

Comment: This also prevents the first white space without requiring the `perl` flag by matching not a boundary:  `gsub('\\B([[:upper:]])', ' \\1', x)`

Answer (score 9):

An answer to your specific question ("how do I split on uppercase letters"?) is

```
strsplit(x="ATextIWantToDisplayWithSpaces", split="[[:upper:]]")
```

but @Ramnath's answer is what you actually want. `strsplit` throws away the characters on which it splits.  The `splitByPattern` function from `R.utils` is closer, but it still won't return the results in the most convenient form for you.

Comment: Doh! You got me this time. :)

Comment: @BenBolker: Thanks for your reply. Comment by kohske is more flexible.

Comment: This answers the specific question: `strsplit(x, "(?!^)(?=[[:upper:]])", perl=T)` . (I would like to know, though, why this doesn't quite work: `strsplit(x, "(?=[[:upper:]])", perl=T)`. In particular, why does it fail in the way that it does?)  @kohske -- as a local regexp guru, do you have any insight?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old one, but I adapted the solution above to one I had where I needed to split the values of a column in a data frame by upper case and then only keep the second element. This solution uses dplyr and purrr:

```
df %>% mutate(stringvar= map(strsplit(stringvar, "(?!^)(?=[[:upper:]])", perl=T),~.x[2]) %>% unlist())
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `stringr`

```
library(stringr)

str_replace_all(
  string =  "ATextIWantToDisplayWithSpaces",
  pattern = "([[:upper:]])",
  replacement = " \\1"
) %>% 
  str_trim()

#[1] "A Text I Want To Display With Spaces"
```