# Split a string based on upper case letters

Tags: regex, r

How to split a string based on each upper case letter it contains. Couldn't find any help from internet.

```
a<-"MiXeD"
b<-"ServiceEventId"
```

I would like to get

```
a<-c("Mi", "Xe", "D")
b<-c("Service", "Event", "Id")
```

Comment: See here for some options (comments on second answer specifically): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988959/splitting-string-based-on-letters-case - strange how that was the **first** result on Google searching for `R Split a string based on upper case letters`, which is essentially your question title. Hmmmm?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22528625/how-to-convert-camelcase-to-not-camel-case-in-r

Comment: @thelatemail Probably worth emphasizing (even though I know *you* know it) that neither of the answers there does what the OP here is asking for. (As you hint, my comment -- the third one below Ben Bolker's answer -- does.)

Comment: @thelatemail, You are referencing a different SO post than the one I referenced.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option, which uses one lookbehind and one lookahead assertion to find (and then split at) intercharacter spaces that are immediately followed by an uppercase letter. To learn why both a lookahead and a lookbehind assertion are needed (i.e. not just a lookahead assertion) [see this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575221/why-does-strsplit-use-positive-lookahead-and-lookbehind-assertion-matches-differ).

```
f <- function(x) {
    strsplit(x, "(?<=.)(?=[[:upper:]])", perl=TRUE)
}

f(a)
# [[1]]
# [1] "Mi" "Xe" "D" 

f(b)
# [[1]]
# [1] "Service" "Event"   "Id"
```

Comment: Just for giggles, here's a `regmatches` adaption - `regmatches(d,gregexpr("([[:upper:]]|^)([^[:upper:]]+|$)",d))`

Answer (score 2):

Use `str_extract_all` from the **stringr** package:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "[A-Z][a-z]*")
```

or

```
str_extract_all(x, "[A-Z][a-z]*|[a-z]+")
```

Comment: I think this falls over if the string starts with lower case or something else - e.g. `"thisIsMixed"`

Comment: `str_extract_all(x, "[A-Z][a-z]*|[a-z]+")`