# Split String by Upper Case Consisting of Both Latin and Unicode

Tags: r, regex, string, unicode, stringr

Building on the [Splitting String based on letters case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988959/splitting-string-based-on-letters-case) answer;

```
lang <- "DeutschEsperantoItalianoNederlandsNedersaksiesNorskРусский"
strsplit(lang, "(?!^)(?=[[:upper:]])", perl = T)
```

results in

```
"Deutsch"      "Esperanto"    "Italiano"     "Nederlands"   "Nedersaksies" "NorskРусский"
```

The problem is the last pair is not separated as Russian is converted to UTF-8 (there will be more variation in the strings; e.g. more or less all other languages in Wikipedia). I checked online Regex testers and other SO answers but they are not much help with R. Tried `iconv` and `Encoding` workarounds in base R as well (can't seem to convert to UTF-16; conversion to bytes doesn't help). Thoughts?

Comment: How about: `(?!^)(?=\p{Lu})`

Comment: Hmm, _fine_. Seriously though, what does that do exactly (it works)?

Comment: `\p{Lu}` is a unicode property that stands for `L` a letter & `u` uppercase in any alphabet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use unicode property `\p{Lu}` that means an uppercase (`u`) letter (`L`) in any alphabet. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

```
lang <- "DeutschEsperantoItalianoNederlandsNedersaksiesNorskРусский"
strsplit(lang, "(?!^)(?=\p{Lu})", perl = TRUE)
```